# Vue cli 3 project ,dynamic src in image path not working

Tags: vue.js, webpack, assets, webpack-dev-server, vue-cli-3

I am referencing an image url in a vue component  like

```
<img alt="Vue logo" src="~statics/reports/logo.png">
```

**this works**

but while trying

```
<img alt="Vue logo" :src="getURL()">


data() {
    return { imgPath: "~statics/reports/logo.png" };
  },

  methods: {

    getURL() {
        // 

      // console.log(path)
      return (this.imgPath)
    }
  },
```

it fails

My folder structure is [image]

In the first case the path is resolved to

```
http://localhost:8081/img/logo.82b9c7a5.png
```

and served automatically by the dev server

The path is not resolved in the second case
it remains `http://localhost:8081/~statics/reports/logo.png`

I am using vue cli 3 generated default config for webpack .

I do not want to use relative paths for all images like ../images/ as it makes it more verbose.
I have tried require(pathVariable) that too does not work
Please help with resolving the img path when the url is dynamic ie asset name comes from server and i append a path in a method or computed and use :src dynamicbinding to serve it

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The second way fails because "~" try to get this asset from node_modules. You can read more about handling assets here:
https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/html-and-static-assets.html#relative-path-imports.

To fix it just use require like below:

```js
data() {
  return {
    imgPath: require('@/statics/logo.png')
  }
}
```

..or directly in template:

```html
<img alt="Vue logo" :src="require('@/statics/logo.png')">
```

Comment: I get `Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: require is not defined`. Do I need to configure something first in order to make this work?

Comment: If you are using `Vite` then require won't work @Fred

Comment: Ah, I got confused about `Vue 3` and `vue-cli 3` (which creates `Vue 2` code) again. Thanks for the heads up!

Answer (score 0):

For Vue 3 projects you can use the following:

```
<img src="./assets/logo.png" />
```

Comment: it's relative path. It doesn't answer the question.

Comment: it didn't work for me in an computed property. i needed to move it to the data function.